# Autohotkey: howto clear most Fnn hotkeys assigned by windows?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, shift, keystrokes

I wanted to program some of the Fnn and shift-Fnn keys, and clear the rest of them from what windows had assigned them.  Just long enough to run a telnet or putty session, then I want to let them revert back to win std.  I used a script in AutoHotkey, and it works mostly, but I assigned the many unused keys to be SHIFT keys, and now the shift-F4 often burps out the unshifted F4 string {over half the time I hit it.}  Is there some better way to nuke the windows presets than just slapping SHIFT on all those keys, or is there some obscure tweak I can make to the script to lighten the load on the SHIFT kbd hook?
Script follows;  note there's lotsa trailing spaces on most lines, if it matters...
Tested on a win8 laptop and an XP tabletop, same results.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
;SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetWorkingDir C:\bin  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
F1::send, EX`r 
F2::Shift         
F3::Shift      
F4::send, FI`r    
F5::Shift       
F6::Shift  
F7::Shift       
F8::Shift     
F9::send, OFF`r   
F10::send, PROD  
F11::send, `r  
F12::send, END`r 
+F1::send, FD   
+F2::Shift   
+F3::Shift   
+F4::send,  EM5 
+F5::Shift        
+F6::Shift  
+F7::Shift    
+F8::Shift    
+F9::send, `r  
+F10::send, PYR`r 
+F11::send, SYSP 
+F12::Shift   
^F12::ExitApp  ; control-F12 will remove all these
$~CapsLock Up::SetCapsLockState Off  ; regress capslock to a SHIFT
```

Comment: Don't you need a return after each keys function to stop it flowing onto the rest of the functions.  Hitting F1 would run like you hit f1 then f2 then f3....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having tried a similar thing to "disable" Windows hold on the WIN key, I found that there wasn't a way to disable all of them - only a few.

However, Autohotkey can override windows hotkeys, as you've found.

If you just want to disable Windows' use of those keys (if I'm understanding you correctly), you could try something like this:

```
F11::
F12::
return
```

That would effectively disable the use of F11 and F12 anywhere as long as the script was running.

*(no, trailing spaces don't make any difference)*